# Unable to install iPhone app from diawi after iOS 9 upgrade?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9, itunes, diawi

I have upgraded my iPhone OS to iOS 9.0. After that I am not able to install the app via IPA file from diawi.
I am able to install it from iTunes.

Is there any solution or alternative to that other than iTunes?

P.S. iPhone Configuration Utility is also crashing on my Mac.

Answer (score 1):

> iOS 9 became more strict with the manifest information:the tag,the
>   value,or something else.

I have met another problem.But I think maybe will give you some useful information.

> *The way to find out why,the most important step is to check you device log.It will show you the installation error information.*

```
I find the problem is that I mistake the bundle-identifier value.
```

> I find if you mistake the bundle-identifier value,the iOS 9 will not allow you to install the app,but iOS 8 or lower version will not check bundle-identifier value.

The installation error information from my iOS 9 device:

```
20:40:09 ifeegoo itunesstored →  <Warning>: [Download]: Download task did finish: 8 for download: 2325728577585828282
20:40:09 ifeegoo itunesstored →  <Warning>: [ApplicationWorkspace] Installing download: 2325728577585828282 with step(s): Install
20:40:09 ifeegoo itunesstored →  <Warning>: [ApplicationWorkspace]: Installing software package with bundleID: com.***.***: bundleVersion: 1.01 path: /var/mobile/Media/Downloads/2325728577585828282/-1925357977307433048
20:40:09 ifeegoo itunesstored →  <Warning>: BundleValidator: Failed bundleIdentifier: com.***.**** does not match expected bundleIdentifier: com.***.*********
20:40:09 ifeegoo itunesstored →  <Warning>: [ApplicationWorkspace]: Bundle validated for bundleIdentifier: com.****.******success: 0
20:40:09 ifeegoo itunesstored →  <Warning>: LaunchServices: Uninstalling placeholder for app <LSApplicationProxy: 0x12677be70> com.****.*******(Placeholder) <file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/B62D8EA3-2052-4393-8A7E-3FD27228BFC2/2325728577585828282.app>
20:40:09 ifeegoo itunesstored →  <Warning>: LaunchServices: Uninstalling app <LSApplicationProxy: 0x12677be70> com.****.*****(Placeholder) <file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/B62D8EA3-2052-4393-8A7E-3FD27228BFC2/2325728577585828282.app>
```

Pay attention to the log(I hide the bundle Id because of privacy.):

```
20:40:09 ifeegoo itunesstored →  <Warning>: BundleValidator: Failed bundleIdentifier: com.***.**** does not match expected bundleIdentifier: com.***.*********
```

The most important to solve this problem is to check the device log.